# Sprint Boot App (Fat JAR) Load external jars

Tags: spring-boot

I have spring boot application (fat jar). But i need to load some external jar's(which are not part of the fat jar). The external jar's contains some `camel` & `spring` components.

Currently when I try to specify the classpath(directory where the external jars are available), the spring boot `@Componentscan` isn't picking up those files.(`java -cp xx`)

How to tell the `spring boot` application to include the external directory where the jar's  are available during `@ComponentScan`.

Appreciate you support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot loading jars (application dependencies and external file system jars)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339925/spring-boot-loading-jars-application-dependencies-and-external-file-system-jars)

Comment: Hi, The @ComponentScan isn't picking up the Camel Routes which are created in those external jar. This is an Spring Boot Application with Camel Routes

Comment: Do you specify base packages?

Comment: you mean for @componentScan. Yes specified.. It's able to load the camel routes in jar's which are packaged within the fat jar.Only the camel routes available in external jars it isn't able to load

Comment: Any help on the above ?.Appreciate your inputs

Comment: Did you try to use `loader.path`?

Comment: yes. tried the loader.path as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339925/spring-boot-loading-jars-application-dependencies-and-external-file-system-jars