# How to add custom launcher to spring-boot-maven's executable jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

How can I add a custom loader to the executable jar?
At the moment i'm doing it manually by opening the jar file, pasting the class and re-signing it the end. -.-

Thanks in advance,
Pedro Silva

Answer (score 0):

### Executable jar restrictions

There are 2 types of restrictions that you need to consider when working with a Spring Boot Loader packaged application.

**Zip entry compression**

The ZipEntry for a nested jar must be saved using the `ZipEntry.STORED` method. This is required so that we can seek directly to individual content within the nested jar. The content of the nested jar file itself can still be compressed, as can any other entries in the outer jar.

**System ClassLoader**

Launched applications should use `Thread.getContextClassLoader()` when loading classes (most libraries and frameworks will do this by default). Trying to load nested jar classes via `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` will fail. Please be aware that java.util.Logging always uses the system classloader, for this reason you should consider a different logging implementation.

### **Alternative single jar solutions**

If the above restrictions mean that you cannot use Spring Boot Loader the following alternatives could be considered:

1. [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)
2. [JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php)
3. [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)

### Resource Link:

1. [The executable jar format](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html)
2. [spring boot loading jars (application dependencies and external file system jars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339925/spring-boot-loading-jars-application-dependencies-and-external-file-system-jars)