# Load spring boot application with spring jars externally placed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Right now, a spring boot application jar/war consists of all spring jars(compile/runtime). This makes application jar/war very heavy and if there are such multiple application then the same spring libraries will be replicated in all application jar/war. This ends up in same spring jars in multiple fat application jar/war. **If there is any way to load these spring jars from common location for all application war?**

Comment: Disks are cheap. This is a non-issue.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible. https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/spring-boot-application-with-exploded-directory-structure/ for instance. However, are you looking for yes/no answer? Or expecting someone to write you a tutorial?

Comment: No.. Why application will eat up space of compute node rather than i can put libraries in storage node? In cloud environment you wont let your compute node waste for storage.

Comment: @eis thanks for sharing this. I got some hint from this. It would be good if you can share some code other than this or any tutorial.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340020/1793718

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad, unless you narrow it down. You can build spring boot app as a regular app, you can explode or unzip it afterwards, you can use jar executables with shared classpath, you can use application servers that provide shared libraries or shared classpath, with and without .war packaging... the question's way too broad as it is. Also, you could give it a try yourself first.